# Angular nested views not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following setup using Angular UI Router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{retailer:[0-9]}',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: '/app/ui/header.html',
        controller: 'HeaderController as header'
      },
      'calendar': {
        templateUrl: '/app/ui/calendar.html',
        controller: 'CalendarController as calendar'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      RETAILER: getRetailer
    }
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: '/app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController as home'
      }
    }
  });
```

My HTML simple looks like:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Then in `home.html` I try to load the calendar view:

```
<div ui-view="calendar"></div>
```

Everything works except the calendar view is not loading. What is being done wrong here?

Comment: I think that you need to move the calendar from the `app` state, into the `app.home` state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home.html is in app.home state and doesn't has 'calendar' views

Answer (score 0):

In you case you try found ui-view with name "calendar" on same level as ui-view with name "header". But, on this level you have just next

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

So, unnamed view, and header view, and not calendar.

When you load "home" with calendar view, this view added **in** home view, instead same level.

So, you have at least to ways:

1. move calendar view to "app.home" state directly, or
2. in app state use [absolute path for view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

   ```
   'calendar@app.home': {
   ```

Sample for second way:

```js
// Code goes here
function getRetailer() {
  return 10;
}
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .controller('HeaderController', function() {
    console.log('header');
  })
  .controller('CalendarController', function() {
    console.log('calendar');
  })
  .controller('HomeController', function() {
    console.log('home');
  })
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/{retailer:[0-9]}',
        views: {
          'header': {
            templateUrl: 'header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderController as header'
          },
          'calendar@app.home': {
            templateUrl: 'calendar.html',
            controller: 'CalendarController as calendar'
          }
        },
        resolve: {
          RETAILER: getRetailer
        }
      })

    .state('app.home', {
      url: '',
      views: {
        '@': {
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'HomeController as home'
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-router@0.3.1" data-semver="0.3.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <a ui-sref="app.home({retailer:1})">Go To App</a>
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view></div>
  <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    Home
    <div ui-view="calendar"></div>
  </script>
  <script id="header.html" type="text/ng-template">Header</script>
  <script id="calendar.html" type="text/ng-template">Calendar</script>
</div>
```